# Error: NumberFormatException dentro de un Asynctask : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: android, android-studio, asynctask

Convierto el numero entero que ingresa el usuario a **hora/minutos/segundos** de la siguiente forma

```
int time = Integer.parseInt(minutos.getText().toString().trim()) * 60 * 1000;
                i.putExtra("tiempo",time);
                startService(i);
```

Y como ven ese numero lo envia a un service y lo ejecuta, el problema es que si lo uso dentro de un `Asynctask` me arroja el siguiente erro en el logcat :

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>                                                                                        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)

Dentro de mi asyn lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            pdLoading.dismiss();

            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                int time = Integer.parseInt(minutos.getText().toString().trim()) * 60 * 1000; // esta es la linea del problema
                i.putExtra("tiempo",time);
                startService(i);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Comienza la cuenta.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Lo curioso que si saco esta función fuera del `async` funciona perfecto.

Comment: Felix, agregué una respuesta, tu respuesta es correcta, pero en ocasiones los usuarios podría introducir un valor no numérico como "a" o "123bc", etc... Esto también provocaría NumberFormatException =(, por experiencia lo mejor es validar si el valor es numérico para realizar la conversión a Integer! :)

Comment: @Jorgesys si ya lo habia pensado, si el editText recibe solamente números, no permite String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si recibes este error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt

indica que no puede realizar la conversión a tipo entero del valor "". En este caso puedes revisar la longitud para saber si el `EditText` tiene contenido,

```
 if(minutos.getText().toString().length()>0 ) {
     //Tiene contenido!
 }else{
     //No tiene contenido.
 }
```

Sin embargo lo anterior aún puede mostrar un mensaje de error si el usuario introduce un valor no numérico.

**La mejor forma de validar que el contenido del `EditText` sea un valor a convertir a entero mediante `Integer.parseInt()` es validar que el valor sea numérico.**

Para esto puedes usar el siguiente método:

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String number){
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        if(number != null){
            Double.parseDouble(number);
            result = true;
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        Log.e(TAG, "NFException value: " + number);
    }
    return result;
}
```

y usarlo de esta forma:

```
if(isNumeric(minutos.getText().toString().trim())) {  //Contiene valor numérico!
     int time = Integer.parseInt(minutos.getText().toString().trim()) * 60 * 1000;
     i.putExtra("tiempo", time);
     startService(i);

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Comienza la cuenta.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}else{
   //No contiene valor numérico!
}
```

Comment: la validación la hice ya(recibe solo numeros), fuera del asyn, si solo necesitaba recibir el numero del editText dentro del asyn, aunque la forma que me dices tambien es funcional ..

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi el problema de la siguiente manera :

```
 if( minutos.getText().toString().length()>0 ) {
                   int time = Integer.parseInt(minutos.getText().toString().trim()) * 60 * 1000;
                   i.putExtra("tiempo", time);
                   startService(i);

                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Comienza la cuenta.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
```

Sucedía que no recibía el numero del `editText` por ende recibia la **exception**. era un error simple, pero había pasado por alto lo básico.