# Problemas con Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " "

Tags: java, crud, excepciones

/*Soy algo nuevo y no comprendo por que me parece aquel error, por lo general siempre es el ultimo valor del *actualizar la tabla* -> pre.setString(5, email);
Estoy tratando de utilizar una tabla y al selecionar el registro este se rrellena automaticamente los campos del formulario, al intenter de editar el formulario me sale el error antes comentado, desconoco la causa e intentado de investigar, pero me gustaria que me explicara el por que sucede para entender el problema, desde ya muchas gracias.*/

//Clase
public class Cliente {

```
private int id_cliente;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private String fono1;
private String email;
private static ConnectionDB connec = new ConnectionDB();

public Cliente() {

}

public Cliente(int id_cliente, String nombre, String apellido, String fono1, String email) {
    this.id_cliente = id_cliente;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.fono1 = fono1;
    this.email = email;
}

public Cliente(String nombre, String apellido, String fono1, String email) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.fono1 = fono1;
    this.email = email;
}
//Visualizar tabla 

public static ArrayList<Cliente> getAllClientes() {
    ArrayList<Cliente> listaDeCliente = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
        PreparedStatement pre = connec.conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = pre.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente(rs.getInt("id_cliente"), rs.getString("nombre"), rs.getString("apellido"), rs.getString("fono1"), rs.getString("email"));
            listaDeCliente.add(cliente);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listaDeCliente;
}

//Insertar datos tabla db
public int insertarCliente() {
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (nombre, apellido, fono1, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pre = connec.conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
        pre.setString(1, nombre);
        pre.setString(2, apellido);
        pre.setString(3, fono1);
        pre.setString(4, email);

        return pre.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}

//Actualizar datos tabla db
public int actualizarCliente() {
    try {
        String sql = "UPDATE cliente SET nombre = ?, apellido = ?, fono1 = ?, email = ? WHERE id_cliente = ?;";
        PreparedStatement pre = connec.conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
        pre.setString(2, nombre);
        pre.setString(3, apellido);
        pre.setString(4, fono1);
        pre.setString(5, email);

        return pre.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

//Jpanel
private void jTable_visualisacionMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

```
    select =  this.jTable_visualisacion.getSelectedRow()+1;
    
    this.jT_idcliente.setText(this.jTable_visualisacion.getValueAt(select, 4).toString());
    this.jTextField_nombre.setText(this.jTable_visualisacion.getValueAt(select, 1).toString());
    this.jTextField_apellido.setText(this.jTable_visualisacion.getValueAt(select, 2).toString());
    this.jTextField_fono.setText(this.jTable_visualisacion.getValueAt(select, 3).toString());
    this.jTextField_email.setText(this.jTable_visualisacion.getValueAt(select, 4).toString());
    
}
```

private void jButton_actualizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:

```
    int id_cliente = Integer.parseInt(jT_idcliente.getText());
    String nombre = jTextField_nombre.getText();
    String apellido = jTextField_apellido.getText();
    String fono1 = jTextField_fono.getText();
    String email = jTextField_email.getText();
    
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente(id_cliente,nombre,apellido,fono1,email);
    if(cliente.actualizarCliente()>0 ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Actualización del producto exitosa!!", "Actualización exitosa", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        listaCliente();
    } else { // si hubo un error en el INSERT, entonces retornará FALSE
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hubo un error al intentar actualizar este Producto", "Error al actualizar", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    limpiar();
}
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error: NumberFormatException dentro de un Asynctask : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117147/error-numberformatexception-dentro-de-un-asynctask-java-lang-numberformatexce)

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo solo debes de contar los signos ?

```
//Actualizar datos tabla db
public int actualizarCliente() {
    try {
        String sql = "UPDATE cliente SET nombre = ?, apellido = ?, fono1 = ?, email = ? WHERE id_cliente = ?;";
        PreparedStatement pre = connec.conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
        pre.setString(2, nombre);
        pre.setString(3, apellido);
        pre.setString(4, fono1);
        pre.setString(5, email);

        return pre.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

En ese caso tienes 5 signos ? quiere decir

```
nombre = ?, apellido = ?, fono1 = ?, email = ? WHERE id_cliente = ?;";
```

Pero no coincide con lo que estas mandando:

```
        pre.setString(2, nombre);
        pre.setString(3, apellido);
        pre.setString(4, fono1);
        pre.setString(5, email);
```

Lo que le mandas se traduce en :

```
         nombre = null, apellido = "nombre", fono1 = "apellido", email = "fono1" WHERE id_cliente = "email";";
```

Por lo tanto al envíar un String en id_cliente te da el error de que no se puede convertir a numero el string enviado ya que el campo id_cliente es numerico.

Cambia el código de la siguiente manera.

```
            pre.setString(1, nombre);
            pre.setString(2, apellido);
            pre.setString(3, fono1);
            pre.setString(4, email);
            pre.setString(5,id_cliente);
```

Comment: De hecho arregle aquel error, muchas gracias! Pero me sigue apareciendo el error -> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "correo@ejemplo.zep]"     Si no estoy equivocado es algo en relación al correo